# There is no valid form to send username and login using Python requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to scrape a website called [quantumonline.com](http://quantumonline.com). There are 2 forms there, neither of which have the respective 'acctname' and 'pswrd' as a values I can fill in. Here is my code:

```
session = requests.session()
data = {
          'acctname':'myusername',
          'pswrd':'mypassword'
       }
session.post('http://quantumonline.com/login.cfm',data=data)
```

Afterward, I try to access a secure page on it using the same session, and it tells me to register. I have also tried using

```
data = {
          'acctname':'myusername',
          'pswrd':'mypassword',
          'submit':'Login'
       }
```

I have no clue why it wont work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check the `action` attribute of the form. The data should be posted to "login_test.cfm".

Comment: did somethign similar to this before, and looks quite about right but the `requests.session()` should be `requests.Session()` (might just be a typo but worth checking). Does it throw any errors your way? What's the response status code and body when you do `session.post('http://quantumonline.com/login.cfm',data=data)`?

Comment: I got the status code 200. How do I retrieve the body?

Comment: I changed the data dictionary so that last attribute is now 'action':'login_test.cfm', but it still doesn't work. :(

Comment: To retrieve the body, I think you just do something like r=session.post() and then r.text See [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

Comment: The message is too long. But the response is just the login screen again. Nothing special. I know the username and password I'm using is correct.

Comment: As Matthias has already pointed out, you should send your `post` requests in this url `http://www.quantumonline.com/login_test.cfm` using the parameters in your second try.

Comment: I send the payload on my second try with the 'action':'login_test.cfm' added to it to the website http://www.quantumonline.com/login_test.cfm, but it still didn't work. If I try to access that website using a browser, it redirects to /login.cfm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website required the requests Session to have gone to the homepage before it tries to submit a login request. Everyone who helped me inch closer to the answer: Thank you.

Here is the working code:

```
session = requests.Session()
data = {
      'acctname':'username',
      'pswrd':'password',
      'action':'login_test.cfm'
   }
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
session.get('http://quantumonline.com', headers=headers) #Get cookies
response = session.post('http://quantumonline.com/login_test.cfm', headers=headers, data=data)
```